# Restrict commands in Linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, security-policy

Is there an option like `Set-ExecutionPolicy` in Linux shell which can be used to restrict commands and scripts?

`Set-ExecutionPolicy` is used in PowerShell: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy

Comment: I don't think so.  Linux permissions don't work like this.  Windows powershell has a breakdown between user, machine, process, etc.  Linux has a much simpler model which boils down to actual file access/execution privs and use of the `/etc/sudoers` file based on a given users/group access to get around the boundaries of those rules.  Hopefully, someone who knows more will come along and correct me.

Comment: Restrict commands in what environment exactly?  If you are asking to restrict PowerShell commands within Linux, that does not exist, if your talking about a command prompt then that would be possible. Likewise, what you can do within bash is pretty limitless, depending on what you are attempting to do.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Ramhound For example if I had to restrict/disable some commands in Fedora default terminal.